# c++ class difference between this and class::

Tags: c++

My understanding is that if I have a class

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();
        void SetVal( int );
    private:
        int val_;
}
```

I can reference a member

```
MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { val_ = val }

MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { MyClass::val_ = val }

MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { this->val_ = val }
```

I like the idea of indicating that a variable is a class member.
Is there any difference between the second and the third approach?

EDIT: made SetVal( int ) public. Been sloppy in writing down the example. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Also: you should make SetVal public, not private.

Comment: _"I like the idea of indicating that a variable is a class member"_ – You seem to be already doing that by suffixing your members with `_`. An additional `this->` or `MyClass::` won't add any extra clarity.

Comment: If you want to easily you know you are accessing a class member why not use the member variable naming convention and use `m_variable_name`?

Comment: Not here, but if val_ is a virtual function `MyClass::val_()` is `MyClass::val_()` and `this->val_()` might be `DerivedClass::val_()`

Comment: *"Is there any difference between the second and the third approach?"* - `this->val_` will survive a class rename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a difference!... Its a [name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) thing

This,

```
MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { val_ = val }
```

does an [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup). where `val_` is first searched in class scope first, if not found, *name-lookup* proceeds to search global *`namespace`* for `val_`. An [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c09f08d6aea86945)

---

This,

```
MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { MyClass::val_ = val }
```

does a [qualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup). where `val_` it is strictly limited to [class namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Class_scope). so if you do not have such member `val_`, it wouldn't go further searching global namespace. Another [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21950d4c141b5b0f)

---

This,

```
MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { this->val_ = val }
```

is similar to the second. [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c9d293f6feba965)

Answer (score 3):

(Presumably in real-life you'd mark `SetVal` `public` or `protected`.)

There is absolutely no difference in your particular case, although I'd plump for `val_ = val` as it's the clearest. Note that `this->` is a tautology.

Note that you can use the `MyClass::val_` notation to descriminate between class members that have been *shadowed* by base and child classes having a class member with that same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { MyClass::val_ = val }
```

This is used for 'static' (not used in your example). Static is common to all instances of a class. To tell the truth, with propper declaration ClassName:: isn't required, but is nonetheless acceptable.

```
MyClass::SetVal( int val ) { this->val_ = val }
```

You coud use this to access the instance field val_, although word 'this' isn't required